# Adding integers to list using sorted and unsorted radio buttons C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a program that adds integers to a list via a text box and button. I also want to include 2 radio buttons that allow the user to either add an item to the listbox in a sorted manner, or in an unsorted manner. This is the code I have so far -

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int acceptedNum = 0;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInsert.Text)) 
   {
       if (!(lstIntegers.Items.Contains(txtInsert.Text)))
       {
           if (!(int.TryParse(txtInsert.Text, out acceptedNum) && acceptedNum <=0 || acceptedNum >= 100))
           {
               lstIntegers.Items.Add(txtInsert.Text);
               txtInsert.Clear();
               txtInsert.Focus();
               bubbleSort();
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Please input value between 1-100", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
               txtInsert.Text = "";
               txtInsert.Focus();
               return;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Number already exists in list", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Please input value between 1-100", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
       txtInsert.Focus();
       return;
   }
   if (lstIntegers.Items.Count == 30)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Maximum number of entries exceeded", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
       //button enabled was false however couldn't then add another 
       btnInsert.Enabled = true;
   }
   if (radSorted.Checked)
       lstIntegers.Items.Add(SortedList < SortOrder>);
}
```

the lines

```
if (radSorted.Checked)
   lstIntegers.Items.Add(SortedList < SortOrder>);
```

are giving me an error, does anyone have any idea how to make a statement so its 'if user has selected radSorted (radio button sorted), then add integer to sorted list. Else if user has checked radUnsorted (radio button unsorted), then add integer to end of list? 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... you only have _one_ `lstIntegers`. Where is your sorted list? What exactly do you want to happen? Should this `lstIntegers` suddenly be sorted? If it's unsorted, how you want to add the next value "sorted"?

Comment: I only have one list, but I want the items in the list to be sorted if the user selects the 'sorted' radio button. If it's unsorted and the user wants to add another integer and change the list to sorted, then the whole list will sort i am hoping.

Comment: The unsorted button just allows the integer to be added onto the end of the list. However if i'm hoping for too much then i could just simplify it and if the sorted button is checked then the list will sort, and if the unsorted button is selected then the integer will just add to the end of the file if this makes more sense.

Comment: improved formatting (intending) for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change these parts your program will work.
change this part:

```
 bubbleSort();
```

to this:

```
if (radSorted.Checked) bubbleSort();
```

and then remove these lines:

```
if (radSorted.Checked)
            lstIntegers.Items.Add(SortedList < SortOrder>);
```

Comment: thank you for the help, however I changed that line and removed the other lines you said to remove and still the items are adding to the end of the list:(

Comment: you should sort your list after adding number.did you do that?

Comment: can you show us your code about bubble sort...it might not work